# Add current date to end of a filename when exporting using to_excel

Tags: python, date

When I run my script I would like to export it as an Excel file with the current date tagged onto the end of it, I could put the date in manually but as I run this each day I would like it to use the current date automatically.

So, to just output an normal excel via python/pandas I use:
df.to_excel('myfile.xlsx')
And in my working directory I get an Excel file called "myfile.xlsx".

But I would like today's current date added to the end, so if I ran the script today the file would be called "myfile 24/09/2019.xlsx".

Comment: on some systems you can't use `/` in file name because system uses it as folders separator. It will try to write file `2019.xlsx` in folder `09` which is in folder `myfile 24` - but first you would have to create these folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you there and employs string formatting for clean / readable code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Create filename from current date.
mask = '%d%m%Y'
dte = dt.now().strftime(mask)
fname = "myfile_{}.xlsx".format(dte)
df.to_excel(fname)
```

As mentioned in a comment above, some OS use `/` as a path separator, so I suggest using a dmY (24092019) date format.  As shown here

Output:

```
myfile_24092019.xlsx
```